# Trouble combining scraped headings and body to create a dictionary I can use in my api

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, fastapi

I'm trying to scrape a table's head and body from a wiki page. I'm building an API but currently, the data is displayed in a list. I want to turn it into a dictionary I think. Basically, the API returns this:

```
 [
    [
    "Bards College",
    "Bards College",
    "Viarmo",
    "Tending the Flames"
    ]
   ]
```

I' like it to look like this:

```
     [
[
    Faction: "Bards College",
    HeadQuarters: "Bards College",
    Leader: "Viarmo",
    Joining condition: "Tending the Flames,
    inhibition condition: ""
    ]
     ]
```

here is my scraping script that uses BS4:

scrape.py:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json


def getLinkData(link):
    return requests.get(link).content

endpoint = "Factions_(Skyrim)"
#endpoint = "Holds"
content = getLinkData(f"https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/{endpoint}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'wikitable'})
thead = soup.find_all("th", {"class": "headerSort"})
data = []
headData = []
skyrim_data = []

for wikiTable in table:        
    table_body = wikiTable.find('tbody')
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        # Get rid of empty values
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

for tableHead in thread:                         # This set of forloops is what 
                                                 #   doesn't work. 
    table_head = tableHead.find('thead')
    head_rows = tableHead.find('tr')
    headings = head_rows.find_all('th')

    for heading in headings:
        #cols = heading.find_all('th')
        #cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        # Get rid of empty values
        headData.append(heading)

more_data = list(filter(lambda x: x != [], headData))    
skyrim_data = list(filter(lambda x: x != [], data))
```

The skyrim_data works correctly, it stores the data scraped.
the more_data does not. it shows up empty.

here is the app.py code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from skyscrape import skyrim_data
from skyscrape import more_data
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def home():
    return("""
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>SkyPI</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>A Skyrim API</h1>
            <h2>Available Endpoints:</h2>
            <ul>
                <a href="/factions"><li>/factions</li></a>
                <a href="/factions"><li>/holds</li></a>
                <a href="/factions"><li>/shouts</li></a>
              
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
    """)

@app.get("/factions")
def factions():
    return skyrim_data
    #return more_data
```

So the end goal here is to have the headings scraped and stored in the more_data array
and then somehow combined with the skyrim_data array to end up with dictionary API like this:

```
  [
[
    Faction: "Bards College",
    HeadQuarters: "Bards College",
    Leader: "Viarmo",
    Joining condition: "Tending the Flames,
    inhibition condition: ""
    ]
     ]
```

In the scraping script, I tried to use the first set of for loops that get the body data to create a new set of for loops that gets the heading data. Then for each list Id want to combine the heading data. This is where I'm completely lost. Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/). It's much easier and faster. I will give an example for the first table, you can do the same for the second by changing the index.

```
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Factions_(Skyrim)'
df = pd.read_html(url)
print(df[0].to_dict(orient='records'))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
   {
      "Faction":"Bards College",
      "Headquarters":"Bards College",
      "Leader":"Viarmo",
      "Joining condition":"Tending the Flames",
      "Inhibition condition":"nan"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"Blades",
      "Headquarters":"Sky Haven Temple",
      "Leader":"Delphine",
      "Joining condition":"A Blade in the Dark",
      "Inhibition condition":"nan"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"Greybeards",
      "Headquarters":"High Hrothgar",
      "Leader":"Paarthurnax",
      "Joining condition":"The Horn of Jurgen Windcaller",
      "Inhibition condition":"Killing Paarthurnax"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"College of Winterhold",
      "Headquarters":"The College of Winterhold",
      "Leader":"Savos Aren",
      "Joining condition":"First Lessons",
      "Inhibition condition":"nan"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"The Companions",
      "Headquarters":"Jorrvaskr",
      "Leader":"Kodlak Whitemane/The Circle",
      "Joining condition":"Take Up Arms",
      "Inhibition condition":"nan"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"The Coven of Namira",
      "Headquarters":"Reachcliff Cave",
      "Leader":"Eola",
      "Joining condition":"The Taste of Death",
      "Inhibition condition":"nan"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"House Telvanni",
      "Headquarters":"Tel Mithryn",
      "Leader":"Neloth",
      "Joining condition":"Old FriendsDR",
      "Inhibition condition":"nan"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"Dark Brotherhood",
      "Headquarters":"Falkreath Sanctuary, Dawnstar Sanctuary",
      "Leader":"Astrid",
      "Joining condition":"Innocence Lost",
      "Inhibition condition":"Destroy the Dark Brotherhood!"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"Imperial Legion",
      "Headquarters":"Castle Dour",
      "Leader":"General Tullius",
      "Joining condition":"Joining the Legion",
      "Inhibition condition":"Joining the Stormcloaks"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"Nightingales",
      "Headquarters":"Nightingale Hall",
      "Leader":"Nocturnal",
      "Joining condition":"Trinity Restored",
      "Inhibition condition":"nan"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"Stormcloaks",
      "Headquarters":"Palace of the Kings",
      "Leader":"Ulfric Stormcloak",
      "Joining condition":"Joining the Stormcloaks",
      "Inhibition condition":"Joining the Legion"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"Thieves Guild",
      "Headquarters":"The Ragged Flagon",
      "Leader":"Mercer Frey",
      "Joining condition":"A Chance Arrangement",
      "Inhibition condition":"nan"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"Tribal Orcs",
      "Headquarters":"Dushnikh Yal, Mor Khazgur, Narzulbur, Largashbur.",
      "Leader":"Chiefs Burguk, Yamarz, Larak & Mauhulakh.",
      "Joining condition":"By doing quests for one of them, thus becoming Blood-Kin.",
      "Inhibition condition":"nan"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"Dawnguard",
      "Headquarters":"Fort Dawnguard",
      "Leader":"Isran",
      "Joining condition":"DawnguardDG",
      "Inhibition condition":"Becoming a vampire in \"Bloodline\"DG"
   },
   {
      "Faction":"Volkihar Clan",
      "Headquarters":"Castle Volkihar",
      "Leader":"Harkon",
      "Joining condition":"Becoming a vampire in \"Bloodline\"DG",
      "Inhibition condition":"Refusing to become a vampire in \"Bloodline\"DG"
   }
]
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. I tried your code and by itself it worked just fine but when I use it as my skyscrape.py code and set skyrim_data = (df[0].to_dict(orient='records')) to pass to the main file. When I run the app I get this error: ValueError: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant.

Comment: dataframe available in the line `skyrim_data = (df[0].to_dict(orient='records'))`?